# Unable to deploy a streamlit app on streamlit cloud

Tags: python, github, keras, streamlit

I am new to stream-lit and I am trying to deploy an app using the stream-lit cloud facility(free version) that can be found here -> https://streamlit.io/cloud

The app that we are building, accepts image inputs through a drag and drop interface and displays outputs to the user. This app is working fine on my local machine.
The GitHub repository for the same can be found here  -> https://github.com/adhok/SeeFood

While deploying on stream-lit cloud using the procedure provided, it gives me the following error.
[image]

I tried restarting the process multiple times but it is giving the same error.

I also tried changing the name of the python file that contains stream-lit front-end functions from `app.py` to `streamlit_app.py` to no avail.

My hypothesis is that the repository is too big (in memory) for the streamlit-cloud interface as there are Keras Model Weights present, without which the model cannot make a prediction.

Please do let me know if there is anything I should change in my repository to make this work.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is a path issue, it will be really hard to fix until someone knows what is going on with your directories. Does the app run well locally?

Comment: Hi, yes the app runs fine locally and I have used relative paths instead of absolute ones

Comment: The Streamlit Cloud team is working to resolve this issue -- I'll comment here again when it's been resolved.

Comment: @adhok This issue should be resolved now -- feel free to reach out if you're still having issues

Answer (score 0):

You can try following steps:

1. Delete you `requirements.txt` file.
2. Open your CMD and run the pip command in your app directory for creating the `requirements.txt` file with all packages along with their
   version command: `pip install pipreqs`.
3. Once `pipreqs` installed then type `pipreqs` in CMD and hit enter button
4. Commit all changes in the Github repo.
5. Try to deploy.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).